# Rename mysql table if exist if not create a new one

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently I'm trying to create a new table using mysqli.
If the table 'default' exist rename it as the current date and time and if not exist create a new table called default.I get date and time from a previous php page that contains current date and time in plain text without / , - , :.
How can I do it using mysqli ?

```
$bk_time=$_POST['system_clock']."backup";
$conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
//check default exist
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM `descript`.`default`;";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

  $sql. = 'RENAME TABLE `default` TO `$bk_time`';
  echo 'exist';
}
else {
 echo 'not exist ';
 $sql. = 'CREATE TABLE `descript`.`default`';
}
mysqli_autocommit($conn, false);
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: What part of this does not work? What is the error you get? Or what does happen while you expect something different to happen? Your code does not look that bad. So why are you asking?

Comment: Result:not exist You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`default`' at line 132
(whether I created the table or not i get the same message)
My code is end in line 90 actually.I can't find the error

Comment: full code is here http://pastebin.com/fW21AVJ1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using stored procedures:

1. To check if table exists
2. To rename table

The first one would be something like the following

```
IF EXISTS (
(SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
    AND TABLE_NAME = _tableName))
    THEN SET _result = 0;
ELSE
    SET _result = 1;
END IF;
```

Comment: I am finding that my table names are not in the information_schema table. My tables were copied from another database for testing purposes.